# Terraform resource 'azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2' not working with Azure Resource Graph Queries

Tags: azure, terraform

I trying to execute the below resource block using the azurerm provider of the terraform for creating an Alert Rule for monitoring the behavior of Azure Update Manager:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "patch_assessment_failure" {
  name                 = "Patch-Assessment-Failure"
  description          = "Alert when the patch assessment operation for a specific VM is failed."
  resource_group_name  = "ospm-rg"
  location             = "northeurope"
  evaluation_frequency = "P1D"
  window_duration      = "P1D"
  scopes               = ["/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/ospm-rg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/ospm-la"]
  severity             = 1

  criteria {
    query = <<-QUERY
      arg('').patchassessmentresources
      | where type in~ ("microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults", "microsoft.hybridcompute/machines/patchassessmentresults")
      | where properties.status =~ "Failed"
      | where properties.lastModifiedDateTime > ago(1d)
      | project vmResourceId
    QUERY

    time_aggregation_method = "Count"
    threshold               = 0
    operator                = "GreaterThan"

    dimension {
      name     = "vmResourceId"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["*"]
    }

    failing_periods {
      minimum_failing_periods_to_trigger_alert = 1
      number_of_evaluation_periods             = 1
    }
  }

  auto_mitigation_enabled = false
  enabled                 = true
  skip_query_validation   = true

  action {
    action_groups = ["/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ospm-rg/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ospm-ag"]
  }
}
```

But, the creation of the resource is failing with the following error:

```
Error: creating Scheduled Query Rule (Subscription: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "ospm-rg"
│ Scheduled Query Rule Name: "Assessment-Failure"): unexpected status 400 with error: DraftClientException: The request had some invalid properties Activity ID: 174a8ae7-808c-4ceb-af13-fce8fdef28fe.
```

As per my observation, the resource query block `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` is not able to execute the Azure Resource Graph Queries because if I remove the `arg('').` part from the query above, terraform apply works absolutely fine giving no errors but the query in the resulting alert rule becomes invalid because the table I am trying to put a query on is not available in the log analytics workspace directly and is coming up from the Azure Resource Graph.

**So, can anyone please provide some suggestions on how we can define an Azure Resource Graph query in the `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` resource block or if there is any workaround available for this issue?**

Comment: Azure Resource Graph queries can't be directly used in azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2 resources; instead, ensure patch assessment data is sent to an Azure Log Analytics workspace and use a KQL query based on that data. Adjust your Terraform query block to target Log Analytics data, not Azure Resource Graph, to resolve the error and create valid alert rules. @altruistcoder

Comment: Thanks for giving a reply. Can you tell if not `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2`, then which terraform resource can be used to create an alert rule on a query that can be directly executed on a Azure Resource Graph?

Also, if this is not possible, can you provide some suggestions on how can we send the patch assessment data to an Azure Log Analytics workspace?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I raised an issue for this problem on the official Github for this azure resource `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` and seems that the Contributors were helpful & have fixed this issue and the new changes will be soon rolling out in the version `3.98.0` of the azurerm provider.

The issue can be referred here for more details:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/25311

Answer (score 0):

> Creating a Terraform Configuration for Azure Monitor Alert on High CPU Usage using log analytics workspace and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The issue you're facing with the `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` resource while attempting to utilize an Azure Resource Graph query underscores a typical problem. The `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` resource is intended for establishing alert rules that are based on queries of data within Azure Monitor Logs (Log Analytics workspaces), rather than directly querying the Azure Resource Graph.

The Azure Resource Graph is a distinct service that enables querying across various resources and subscriptions. However, its queries cannot be directly executed within Azure Monitor Log Analytics workspaces.

I made the changes in the requirement and rewrite the code below.

***Terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "testvk-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "testvk-loganalytics"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "example" {
  name                = "highvk-cpu-usage-alert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  evaluation_frequency = "PT15M" # Every 15 minutes
  window_duration      = "PT15M"
  scopes               = [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id]
  severity             = 4

  criteria {
    query = <<-QUERY
      Perf
      | where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total"
      | summarize AvgCPUUsage = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
      | where AvgCPUUsage > 80
    QUERY
    time_aggregation_method = "Average"
    threshold               = 80
    operator                = "GreaterThan"
    metric_measure_column   = "AvgCPUUsage" # Correctly specify the metric measure column

    failing_periods {
      minimum_failing_periods_to_trigger_alert = 1
      number_of_evaluation_periods             = 1
    }
  }

  action {
    action_groups = ["/subscriptions/subscription_ID/resourceGroups/Resourcegroupname/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/testvmsb"]
    custom_properties = {
      "Alert" = "High CPU Usage Detected"
    }
  }

  tags = {
    "Purpose" = "Demo"
  }
}
```

***Note:*** Replace the KQL query mentioned as per your own requirement.

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently. The alert needs to be granted access to query the Resource Graph. This is supported by using an assigned identity. Unfortunately this is not yet supported by `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/23437). I was still able to provision the alert with Terraform using the `azapi_resource` instead. You could use something like this (wasn't sure how to map dimensions):

```
resource "azapi_resource" "patch_assessment_failure" {
  type       = "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules@2022-08-01-preview"
  name       = "Patch-Assessment-Failure"
  parent_id  = azurerm_resource_group.this.id
  location   = azurerm_resource_group.this.location

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      description          = "Alert when the patch assessment operation for a specific VM is failed."
      displayName          = "Resource Alert"
      severity             = 1
      evaluationFrequency  = "P1D"
      windowSize           = "P1D"
      scopes               = ["/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/ospm-rg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/ospm-la"]
      criteria             = {
        allOf = [
          {
            query                = <<-QUERY
              arg('').patchassessmentresources
              | where type in~ ("microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults", "microsoft.hybridcompute/machines/patchassessmentresults")
              | where properties.status =~ "Failed"
              | where properties.lastModifiedDateTime > ago(1d)
              | project vmResourceId
            QUERY
            timeAggregation      = "Count"
            dimensions           = []
            resourceIdColumn     = ""
            operator             = "GreaterThan"
            threshold            = 0
            failingPeriods       = {
                numberOfEvaluationPeriods = 1
                minFailingPeriodsToAlert  = 1
            }
          }
        ]        
      }
      autoMitigate                          = false
      checkWorkspaceAlertsStorageConfigured = false
      skipQueryValidation                   = false
    }
  })
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "assign_reader_alert" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.this.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = azapi_resource.patch_assessment_failure.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks a lot for providing a reply. 

I was able to do a workaround for my issue already using the same approach as you have mentioned basically by making use of `azapi_resource` to make an API call directly to the latest API version `2023-03-15-preview`. This solved both the issues of executing a query directly on Azure Resource Graph as well as providing an identity block for the Alert Rule. And, I managed to specify the dimensions in it as well.